# Excel VBA - Act on each row in a range based on first cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet containing multiple rows, each with the same fields. The first column contains a Group ID. Each row may have a different Group, and they be mixed up. There may be any number of different Group IDs. I want to go through the range, and for each Group ID perform an action on the row.

```
Group   ID
A   d001
A   d002
B   d003
A   d004
B   d005
C   d006
B   d007
C   d008
```

The output would be something like:

```
Group A:
d001
d002
d004
Group B:
d003
d005
d007
Group C:
d006
d008
```

This seems to be like an SQL 'WHERE" statement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are basically letting us do all the work. First of all, you should think of an algorithm to approach this objective (i.e. iterate over it, save groups in array, iterate again and try to complete single groups OR save the members ... etc) and then try to achieve it yourself in VBA. It's not that hard and SO is not meant to write your code, but to help you with problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Sub test()
Dim oCell As Range, i&, LRow&, KeyGR As Variant, KeyIdGr
Dim Group As Object: Set Group = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim IdGroup As Object: Set IdGroup = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
i = 1
LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Each oCell In Range("A2:A" & LRow)
    If Not Group.exists(oCell.Value) And oCell.Value <> "" Then
        Group.Add oCell.Value, i: i = i + 1
    End If
Next
For Each oCell In Range("B2:B" & LRow)
    If Not Group.exists(oCell.Value) And oCell.Value <> "" Then
        IdGroup.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, -1).Value
    End If
Next
i = 1
For Each KeyGR In Group
    Cells(i, "C").Value = "Group " & KeyGR & ":"
    i = i + 1
    For Each KeyIdGr In IdGroup
        If IdGroup(KeyIdGr) = KeyGR Then
            Cells(i, "C").Value = KeyIdGr
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

final result

[image]

Comment: That works great, thank you very much @Vasily. I have to change it to work in a different sheet, and then to write to a file instead of to the sheet. But I guess I should do some of the work at least.